Getting the invalidelementstateexception: message: invalid element state
In our application, we have one editor where I need to enter the data , but it is Div . This is my outer HTML of the element for reference
<div class="view-lines monaco-mouse-cursor-text" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" data-mprt="8" style="position: absolute; font-family: &quot;Fira Code&quot;, Menlo, Monaco, &quot;Courier New&quot;, monospace; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; font-feature-settings: &quot;liga&quot;, &quot;calt&quot;; font-variation-settings: normal; line-height: 18px; letter-spacing: 0px; width: 1590px; height: 61px;"><div style="top:5px;height:18px;" class="view-line"><span><span></span></span></div></div>

When I used the code below to input text in robot getting the exception
Input text    //div[@class='view-lines monaco-mouse-cursor-text']    ${query}


Getting the invalidelementstateexception: message: invalid element state

You need to activate the input element and use it as the locator for Input Text. Try to click on the div element and then inspect the page for the input element.

There is no input element after clicking as well
for eg :
'''
test
'''
The above value is the outerhtml after clicks on that and type "test" in the editor.
I tried using pywinauto send_keys , which is kind of working but it is not typing with spaces

There should exist a HTML element <input type='text'  so you can use Input Text.

unfortunately there is no input  , to make it more clear, this is not a typical text area. here user should provide one query [ something similar to SQL]
